# Center aligning a text horizontally and vertically in a div element

Tags: html, css

> I have made a div of fixed height and I want the text to align both
> vertically and horizontally in the div.
>
> I tried using margin:auto and
> text-align but it didn't help.
>
> I am beginner HTML/CSS.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:20px; height:400px;">
      <h2>London</h2>
      
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Actually we should have got answer without using transform but actually it is not aligning perfectly in center. Why?  And What is the actual role of transform?

Comment: Position with top left of 50% sets the top left corner of the h2 dead center within it's parent. Transform is used to move it back 50% relative to the h2's dimensions so it visually appears in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
.align{
  text-align: center;           
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
    <div>
      <h2>London</h2>

    </div>
```